# explorer.exe crashes when right clicking a .ts file

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, context-menu

I have a Windows 10 machine with many .ts (`typescript`) files. The problem is that suddenly, whenever I right click this file type my PC freezes and after a few seconds it looks like the `explorer.exe` process resets (all windows disappear for a couple of seconds and get back after). I tried removing all 3rd party extensions using the `shexview` utility but it didn't help. also, in safe mode right clicking the files works fine.
Any suggestions on what's causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: [capture a crash dump](http://pastebin.com/WACz5GBU) and share the compressed dump. I'll analyze the dump

Comment: have you created a crash dump of explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the dmp with Windbg.exe, shows that the `CompPkgSup.DLL` casues the crash:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

FAULTING_IP: 
CompPkgSup!AreDvdCodecsEnabledInternal+3c1
00007ffa`69f4349d 488b03          mov     rax,qword ptr [rbx]

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 00007ffa69f4349d (CompPkgSup!AreDvdCodecsEnabledInternal+0x00000000000003c1)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[1]: 0000000000000000
Attempt to read from address 0000000000000000

PROCESS_NAME:  explorer.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - Die Anweisung in 0x%08lx verweist auf Speicher 0x%08lx. Der Vorgang %s konnte nicht im Speicher durchgef hrt werden.

PROBLEM_CLASSES: 

    ID:     [0n292]
    Type:   [@ACCESS_VIOLATION]
    Class:  Addendum
    Scope:  BUCKET_ID
    Name:   Omit
    Data:   Omit
    PID:    [Unspecified]
    TID:    [0x4d50]
    Frame:  [0] : CompPkgSup!AreDvdCodecsEnabledInternal

    ID:     [0n264]
    Type:   [INVALID_POINTER_READ]
    Class:  Primary
    Scope:  BUCKET_ID
    Name:   Add
    Data:   Omit
    PID:    [Unspecified]
    TID:    [0x4d50]
    Frame:  [0] : CompPkgSup!AreDvdCodecsEnabledInternal

    ID:     [0n279]
    Type:   [NULL_POINTER_READ]
    Class:  Primary
    Scope:  DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID (Failure Bucket ID prefix)
            BUCKET_ID
    Name:   Add
    Data:   Omit
    PID:    [0x4fa4]
    TID:    [0x4d50]
    Frame:  [0] : CompPkgSup!AreDvdCodecsEnabledInternal

    ID:     [0n105]
    Type:   [AFTER_CALL]
    Class:  Addendum
    Scope:  DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID (Failure Bucket ID prefix)
            BUCKET_ID
    Name:   Add
    Data:   Omit
    PID:    [0x4fa4]
    TID:    [0x4d50]
    Frame:  [0] : CompPkgSup!AreDvdCodecsEnabledInternal

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_NULL_POINTER_READ_INVALID_POINTER_READ_AFTER_CALL

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_POINTER_READ_AFTER_CALL

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  APPLICATION_FAULT

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 00007ffa69f4425e to 00007ffa69f4349d

STACK_TEXT:  
00 ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects
01 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx
02 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjects
03 kernel32!WerpReportFaultInternal
04 kernel32!WerpReportFault
05 KERNELBASE!UnhandledExceptionFilter
06 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart$filt$0
07 ntdll!_C_specific_handler
08 ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException
09 ntdll!RtlDispatchException
0a ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatch
0b CompPkgSup!AreDvdCodecsEnabledInternal
0c CompPkgSup!Windows::Internal::ComTaskPool::CTaskWrapper<<lambda_f3a4475443bbb44b21d50bb6ae79976e> >::Run
0d CompPkgSup!Windows::Internal::ComTaskPool::CThread::_ThreadProc
0e CompPkgSup!Windows::Internal::ComTaskPool::CThread::s_ExecuteThreadProc
0f CompPkgSup!Windows::Internal::ComTaskPool::CThread::s_ThreadProc
10 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk
11 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart


BUCKET_ID_PREFIX_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_NULL_POINTER_READ_INVALID_POINTER_READ_AFTER_CALL_

FAILURE_PROBLEM_CLASS:  APPLICATION_FAULT

FAILURE_SYMBOL_NAME:  CompPkgSup.DLL!AreDvdCodecsEnabledInternal

WATSON_STAGEONE_URL:  http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/explorer.exe/10.0.14393.953/58ba5aa4/CompPkgSup.DLL/10.0.14393.953/58ba5c12/c0000005/0000349d.htm?Retriage=1


start             end                 module name
00007ffa`69f40000 00007ffa`69f4c000   CompPkgSup   (pdb symbols)          d:\sym\dl\Co\CompPkgSup.pdb\D52AAD1B60D7453DA0B36706C2E3939D1\CompPkgSup.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: CompPkgSup.DLL
    Image path: C:\Windows\System32\CompPkgSup.DLL
    Image name: CompPkgSup.DLL
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Sat Mar  4 07:17:54 2017 (58BA5C12)
    CheckSum:         000191EA
    ImageSize:        0000C000
    File version:     10.0.14393.953
    Product version:  10.0.14393.953
    File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
    File OS:          40004 NT Win32
    File type:        2.0 Dll
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04b0
    CompanyName:      Microsoft Corporation
    ProductName:      Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
    InternalName:     Component Package Support DLL
    OriginalFilename: CompPkgSup.dll
    ProductVersion:   10.0.14393.953
    FileVersion:      10.0.14393.953 (rs1_release_inmarket.170303-1614)
    FileDescription:  Component Package Support DLL
    LegalCopyright:   © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

This looks like the known DVD decode issue with the [Update KB4013429](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4013429), that is fixed in [KB4015438](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4015438):

> Addressed a known issue with KB4013429 that caused Windows DVD Player
>   (and 3rd party apps that use Microsoft MPEG-2 handling libraries) to
>   crash.

So looks like Explorer tries to generate thumbnails and crashes because of the bug.

So, the best is to [download and install](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=KB4016635) the latest update [KB4016635 (OS Build 14393.970)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4016635) to fix your issue.